# Поиск в объекте по числу

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста. Имею поле поиска и объект:

```js
// Перебираю атрибут name у кнопок и добавляю их в объект
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let objects = {};
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const button = elements[i];
  objects[[button.name]] = {
    name: button.name
  };
}

// Создаю поиск
var form = document.querySelector('#search');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(form);
  var num = data.get('num');
  console.log(num)
  var numfull = data.get('num')
  if (objects[num]) {
    console.log(objects[num]);
    // document.location.replace(objData2[num]);
  } else if (objects[numfull]) {
    console.log(objects[numfull]);
  } else {
    console.log('Not found');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <form id="search">
    <input type="text" name="num" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Например есть объект

```
{ 
    N01 - Number 01: {name: "N01 - Number 01"}
    N15 - Number 15: {name: "N15 - Number 15"}
}
```

В поиске ввели число 15 в консоли отобразился объект `{name: "N15 - Number 15"}`, ввели число 01 в консоли отобразился объект `{name: "N01 - Number 01"}`.

Любая помощь будет полезна, заранее спасибо.

Comment: А если ввели "1"?

Comment: Тогда должен выводить окно "не найдено".

Comment: `buttonObjects` это тот самый объект в к-м искать число?

Comment: Да да брат, это то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант.

```js
var object = { 
    "N01 - Number 01": {name: "N01 - Number 01"},
    "N15 - Number 15": {name: "N15 - Number 15"}
};

var form = document.querySelector('#form-search');

form.onsubmit = function(){ 
  
  var value = this.querySelector('#form-input-search').value.trim();
  var valid = null;
  
  if(value.match(/^\N[0-9]+.+[0-9]+$/)){
    valid = value.match(/^\N[0-9]+.+[0-9]+$/);
  } else {
    var source = "N{{search}} - Number {{search}}";
    source = source.replace(/{{search}}/g, value);
    valid = source.match(/^\N[0-9]+.+[0-9]+$/);
  }
    
  if(valid){
    
    if(object[valid]){
      console.log(object[valid]);
    } else {
      console.log("поиск не дал результатов");
    }
    
  } else {
    console.log("неверный формат");
  }
  return false;
  
}
```

```html
<form id="form-search">
  <input type="text" id="form-input-search">
  <button>Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Брат это близко к тому, что я хотел, остаётся только сделать так, чтобы этот поиск работал как только с введённым числом, так и со всей стракой. Например я ввожу N01 - Number 01 он мне возвращает Object {name: "N01 - Number 01"} и желательно это сделать в форме поиска, чтобы кнопкой можно было поискать. 
Заранее спасибо.
P.S. один час бьюсь над этим, но не получается.

Comment: У меня есть поиск, но не он не работает так как нужно, т.е. он может найти только по полному названию и как совместить твой код с моим или мой код с твоим не понимаю. А вот и фрагмент на JS
var form = document.querySelector('#search-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var num = data.get('num');
    if (buttonObjects[num]) {
      console.log(Objects[num]);
        // document.location.replace(Objects[num]);
    } else {
      console.log('Not found');
    }
}) В HTML id изменил на search-form

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk обновил код. Проверяй)

Comment: Только что увидел, это то что надо. От души в душу брат :)

Comment: Брат, а как сделать, чтобы результат записывался скажем в главный div?